# jquery won't save filled input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var sheet = document.getElementById("myList").value;
var sheett = document.getElementById("value_Bruto_1").value;

if ((sheet == "one") && (sheett == "Neto")) {
  $('#revertall_edited2')[0].click();
  $('#inlineAdd2')[0].click();
  $('#inlineAdd2')[0].click();
  var text_value = $("#value_Za_uplatu_1").val();
  var newValue = (+text_value / 1.2).toFixed(2);
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('input:eq(0)').val(9);
    $('input:eq(27)').val(1);
    $('input:eq(31)').val(newValue);
  }, 3000);
}
else if (sheet == "two") {
  alert('Choose');
}
else if (sheet == "three") {
  alert('Choose');
}
else {
  alert('Choose');
}

return true;
```

Greetings, I'm trying to save autofill fields in database with that code under. When i press save button, autofilled fields will be empty saved, but if I in some other fields manual add some value then it will works. i searched forum and founded focus but can someone give me example how to use on my code. Thanks in advance from newbie.
[Here is image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1sZG.png)

P.S. Code is too big for post and have many files. I hope this can help in explanation.

Comment: Nop even when i comment that 3 lines still autofilled fields wont be saved.

Comment: Post a complete code example that reproduces the problem please. Also, if you're using jQuery, why are you doing things like `document.getElementById("myList").value;` instead of `$('#myList').val()`?

Comment: I cant post complete code, because it have many files, but i posted image for help. Please look at image. Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like your code has at least a few typo problems. Also unclear what you mean by "saving autofill fields".  I see no concept of "saving" (even in at all in your code example - not to a back-end system, not to session cookie, nothing. For that reason it is pretty much impossible for me to provide any guidance that would help you.  You basically seem like you are trying to build a whole user interface but don't know how to go about doing it.